# Upgrading Grails Shiro application to Spring Security Shiro, bypassing @Secured("permitAll")

Tags: grails, spring-security, shiro

I have a grails shiro application that I would like to update to grails 3. I currently have to add **@Secured("permitAll")** to all controller actions. I have roughly 20 controllers and each has nearly 20 actions. Is there a way to bypass the spring security check as the actions for the older application already perform a authorization check.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the 5.1. Pessimistic Lockdown section of the documentation:
https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html

Comment: Before you posted this I manually added all the controllers to `grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules.` Much cleaner solution. Thank you